# Python itertools groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

Let's say, I have the following list of tuples

```
[('FRG', 'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '), 
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'),
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4')
('FRG2', 'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '), 
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4')]
```

How do I group these to have a a dict in the end like:

```
{'FRG': ['MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'],
 'FRG2': ...}
```

That is to say, I'd like to glue together the parts where the `tuple[0]` is a word with the (potentially numerous) following parts where the `tuple[0]` is empty (contains only whitespaces).
I was experimenting with `groupby` and `takewhile` from `itertools` but haven't reached any working solution. Ideally, the solution contains one of these (for learning purposes, that is).

Comment: will they keys always start with `FRG`?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: No, but always with word characters (`\w+`).

Comment: So how will we know what is a key and what is not, since the values are also word characters

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: As said in the question, it's always the **first** value of the tuple.

Comment: you can use `itertools.groupby` to get the keys but in terms of a complete solution I have to agree with @Rawing, I've been trying to come up with one that exclusively uses `itertools` and am coming up blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `groupby` and `takewhile` aren't good fits for this sort of problem.

### `groupby`

[`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) groups based on a `key` function. That means you need to keep the last encountered first non whitespace tuple element to make it work. That means you keep some global state around. By keeping such a state the function is said to be ["unpure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) while most (or even all) itertools are pure functions.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

d = [('FRG',                  'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '), 
     ('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF',     'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'),
     ('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF',     'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'),
     ('FRG2',                 'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '), 
     ('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF',     'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4')]

def keyfunc(item):
    first = item[0]
    if first.strip():
        keyfunc.state = first
    return keyfunc.state

{k: [item for idx, item in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(grp)) if idx%3 != 0] for k, grp in groupby(d, keyfunc)}
```

### `takewhile`

[`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) needs to look ahead to determine when to stop `yield`ing values. That means it will automatically pop one value more from the iterator than actually used for each group. To actually apply it you would need to remember the last position and then create a new iterator each time. It also has the problem that you would need to keep some sort of state because you want to take one element with not-space first element and then the ones that have an space-only first element.

One approach could look like this (but feels unnecessarily complicated):

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice

def takegen(inp):
    idx = 0
    length = len(inp)
    while idx < length:
        first, *rest = inp[idx]
        rest = list(rest)
        for _, *lasts in takewhile(lambda x: not x[0].strip(), islice(inp, idx+1, None)):
            rest.extend(lasts)
        idx += len(rest) // 2
        yield first, rest

dict(takegen(d))
```

### Alternative

You could simply create your own generator to make this quite easy. It's a variation of the `takewhile` approach but it doesn't need external state, `islice`, `takewhile`, `groupby` or that one keeps track of the index:

```
def gen(inp):
    # Initial values
    last = None
    for first, *rest in inp:
        if last is None:       # first encountered item
            last = first
            l = list(rest)
        elif first.strip():    # when the first tuple item isn't all whitespaces
            # Yield the last "group"
            yield last, l
            # New values for the next "group"
            last = first
            l = list(rest)
        else:                  # when the first tuple item is all whitespaces
            l.extend(rest)
    # Yield the last group
    yield last, l

dict(gen(d))
# {'FRG2': ['MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'], 
#  'FRG': ['MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4']}
```

Comment: @planetp Yeah, just with more explanation why the `groupby` and `takewhile` aren't good approaches to solve the problem and the answers contain different implementations. Could you be more specific what makes the answers so similar that you felt you need to downvote? You also might want to take a look at the [downvote-help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) which contains a few guidelines "when it's appropriate to downvote".

Answer (score 3):

Not that I recommend it, but to use `itertools.groupby()` for this, you'd need a key function that remembers the last used key. Something like this:

```
def keyfunc(item, keys=[None]):
    if item[0] != keys[-1] and not item[0].startswith(" "):
        keys.append(item[0])        
    return keys[-1] 

d = {k: [y for x in g for y in x[1:]] for k, g in groupby(lst, key=keyfunc)}
```

A simple `for` loop looks cleaner and doesn't requre any `import`s:

```
d, key = {}, None
for item in lst:
    if item[0] != key and not item[0].startswith(" "):
        key = item[0]
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(item[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using [***collections.defaultdict***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) subclass:

```
l = [('FRG', 'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '),
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'),
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'),
('FRG2', 'MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE '),
('                    ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4')]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
k = ''
for t in l:
    if t[0].strip():  # if the 1st value of a tuple is not empty
        k = t[0]      # capturing dict key
    if k:
        d[k].append(t[1])
        d[k].append(t[2])

print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{'FRG2': ['MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4'], 'FRG': ['MCO TPA PIE SRQ', 'WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE ', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4', 'FMY RSW APF', 'WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4']}
```